# baud rate of st8024 when working with stm32f103

Tags: c, embedded, stm32f1

I am working with stm32f103 and I want to work with st8024 and smart card.

but with hsc1.Init.BaudRate = 115200; , I do not receive 0x3b or 0x3f in TS of ATR.

```
/* USART1 init function */
static void MX_USART1_SMARTCARD_Init(void)
{

    hsc1.Instance = USART1;
    hsc1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
    hsc1.Init.WordLength = SMARTCARD_WORDLENGTH_9B;
    hsc1.Init.StopBits = SMARTCARD_STOPBITS_1_5;
    hsc1.Init.Parity = SMARTCARD_PARITY_EVEN;
    hsc1.Init.Mode = SMARTCARD_MODE_TX_RX;
    hsc1.Init.GuardTime = 0;
    hsc1.Init.NACKState = SMARTCARD_NACK_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_SMARTCARD_Init(&hsc1) != HAL_OK)
    {
       Error_Handler();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for your parts? 115200 is a very high baudrate for embedded systems like these.

Comment: What do you receive, then? Do you get overrun or framing errors? Did you measure the signal with an oscilloscope?

Comment: I have read ISO 7816 but I did not find any thing about baud rate
and this baud rate has been generated by cube.

Comment: @Lundin I think I do not have framing error. I receive 0x8A. and when I change the baudrate this number changes.

Comment: 115200 is fine depending on the clock frequency you have set.  in what order to you initialize the clock relative to the uart?  the uart divisor generally comes from the main clock or a derivative.